# How can I ensure multiple table columns are unique (or restructure my tables) in MySQL using Innodb?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, innodb

I currently have two separate tables with a third to be added which store recipes, items and custom_meal (the one to be created).

I am looking to create a Meal Planner where the user may add either a recipe, item or custom item as their breakfast/lunch/dinner for a specific day.

I have an idea for my new tables below although going down this path I would have no way of ensuring that the meal_planner.id can only be either a recipe, item or custom.
With well written queries I realise that this should never be allowed to be an issue, although as someone with a great deal still to learn about databases I would much prefer a solution that ensures data may never be entered when it shouldn't be.

The current columns of interest on tables I'm already using are:

```
recipe.id  
item.id
user.id
```

My current thoughts on the "Meal Planner" tables would be:

Table: meal_planner

```
id - primary key
user_id - foreign key user.id
mdate - the day which the meal is planned for
mtime - whether the meal is breakfast, lunch or dinner.
mcomment (can be null)
```

Table: meal_is_recipe

```
meal_id - foreign key meal_planner.id
recipe_id - foreign key recipe.id
```

Table: meal_is_custom

```
meal_id - foreign key meal_planner.id
custom_id - foreign key custom_meal.id
```

Table: meal_is_item

```
meal_id - foreign key meal_planner.id
item_id - foreign key item.id
```

Table: custom_meal

```
id - primary key
user_id - foreign key user.id
name - varchar to hold the name of the meal
```

This should allow me to use joins to grab all the required data for display although as mentioned it bugs me that their is no constraint stopping a meal.id being used in recipe, item and/or custom.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so since posting this I have discovered "triggers".

Triggers are similar to a stored procedure although in a triggers case they will fire automatically when the set condition is met, for example before completing an insert, update or delete on a table.

In my case I have created six triggers, two for each meal_is_x table to check if the meal_id already exists in one of the other tables and return an error instead of the insert if it does.

I didn't have any luck through the phpmyadmin query using examples so I created my triggers in phpmyadmin by selecting the database, clicking on the Triggers tab, clicking add new trigger and then entering the following (modified slightly for each different table and whether it was for insert or update).

Trigger name: `meal_is_recipe_BeforeInsert`

Table: `meal_is_recipe`

Time: `BEFORE`

Event: `INSERT`

Definition:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE custom_match INT;
    DECLARE item_match INT;
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO custom_match FROM meal_is_custom
    WHERE meal_id = NEW.meal_id;
    IF custom_match > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'A Custom record with that meal id already exists';
    ELSE
        SELECT COUNT(1) INTO item_match FROM meal_is_item
        WHERE meal_id = NEW.meal_id;
        IF item_match > 0 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An Item record with that meal id already exists';
        END IF;
    END IF;
END
```

Definer: I left this blank as the user that made the query if fine to run the trigger.

I believe I should also have been able to get the same result with the MySQL query but as I mention this did not work straight away for me in phpmyadmin and rather than look into it further the triggers tab was simple enough:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER meal_is_recipe_BeforeInsert BEFORE INSERT ON meal_is_recipe
BEGIN
    DECLARE custom_match INT;
    DECLARE item_match INT;
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO custom_match FROM meal_is_custom
    WHERE meal_id = NEW.meal_id;
    IF custom_match > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'A Custom record with that meal id already exists';
    ELSE
        SELECT COUNT(1) INTO item_match FROM meal_is_item
        WHERE meal_id = NEW.meal_id;
        IF item_match > 0 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An Item record with that meal id already exists';
        END IF;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

As I mentioned in the question my knowledge working with databases still has a long way to go so whilst I have tested this with my initial question schema and it works, I cannot guarantee this is the most efficient way of achieving the outcome.